# parse.com sessions in php-sdk

Tags: php, wordpress, parse-platform

I am new in WordPress and PHP. I am using php-sdk of parse.com for developing my plugin. My php-sdk folder is inside my plugin folder. I have stored App ID , Rest API key and Master key in my database of WordPress.

For Parse initialization, I required App ID , Rest API key and Master key. I can fetch it from my WordPress database.

After parse initialization, I can fetch my data from parse. For fetching data you have to authenticate first. username and password are required to authentication. I am getting these username and password by a form. When I am submitting my form then I am initializing the parse and then authenticating it. I can fetch the data on same page as well. But I am going to other page then I can not get the data. I try to use following code on other page :

```
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseUser;
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
if ($currentUser) {
// do stuff with the user
echo "username: ". $currentUser->getObjectId();
} else {
// show the signup or login page
echo "Not Found";
}
```

I could not get my current user. How can I maintain the sessions in parse.com. I want to initialize and authenticate the users once for all. After that I can get the data from any of the page of my WordPress. How to solve this problem ? Can any body help me ??

Comment: Try moving the session_start() to after the autoload require.. If that doesn't fix it, add the code for how you're logging in.

Comment: @Fosco have u ever used parse php sdk ???

Comment: tell me just a general question. I want to initialize my parse once and want to get the data from any of my site page. How I will store the session of my parse initialization. @Fosco

Comment: You can put the initialize call in one spot, but it needs to be required/included everywhere.  You don't store the parse initialization, but you can store a user... $_SESSION['myuser'] = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

Comment: include means you are initializing parse every time which is a bad solution to my problem.

Comment: Initializing doesn't make any network calls.  It's unavoidable, must be done for the SDK to know which app will be making requests.  It's not a bad solution to your problem, you just haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

After `session_start()` use:

```
\Parse\ParseClient::initialize(....);
\Parse\ParseClient::setStorage(new \Parse\ParseSessionStorage());
```

Comment: tell me one thing, how can i set the session storage for other tables in parse just i did for User table ???

Comment: There is no solution out of the box, but tell me:
- how many data object you will store in a user session?
- and how long should the data be available in the session?

Comment: the data should be available until user log out. I can maintain the session for user tables but I can not maintain the session for other tables like Role, Product and my own custom tables